# Evaluating bash variable after assignment

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement, variable-assignment, evaluation

I am writing a small bash script that needs to check the output of a web service which is in JSON. If the value of a particular JSON field is "success", the script should simply echo 0. The script is used as a deployment hook with a different web service, hence I have no choice over what it needs to return.

I have gotten to the point where I can easily parse the JSON (using jq) and echo the value of the field I am interested in.

```
result=$(curl https://www.cloudflare.com/api_json.html \
-d 'a=zone_file_purge' \
-d 'tkn=###########################' \
-d 'email=#########################' \
-d 'z=#############################' \
-d 'url=###########################' \
| jq '.result'); echo $result;
```

will indeed echo "success". In other words, the value of the variable $result is "success".

But if I do this:

```
result=$(curl https://www.cloudflare.com/api_json.html \
-d 'a=zone_file_purge' \
-d 'tkn=###########################' \
-d 'email=#########################' \
-d 'z=#############################' \
-d 'url=###########################' \
| jq '.result'); if [ "$result" == "success" ]; then echo 0; else echo $result; fi
```

the script still echoes:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
310   148    0   148    0   162    116    127 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
"success"
```

I have also tried

```
if [ "$result" = "success" ];
```

and

```
if [ $result == "success" ];
```

and

```
if [ $result = "success" ];
```

but the result is always the same. This makes absolutely no sense to me since "success" should be the same as "success" and should therefore echo 0.

I know that this is something very simple for bash experts, which I am not. I will be most grateful for your tips.

Comment: You have quotes missing. The content of `result` is `"success"` with quotes. Hence `[ "$result" = '"success"' ]` should work.

Comment: That's exactly what it is! Many thanks.